# connect internal only until freed oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi im trying to connect to oracle server db using oracle Sql developer
Im getting error as

> connect internal only until freed

Please let me know how to solve this error.

Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you the DBA of this database?  If not, you'll need to contact the DBA-- this error indicates that the database is, essentially, down.  There is nothing that an end user could do to fix this error.

If you are the DBA, what version of Oracle are you using?  The most common problem is that the directory (or one of the directories depending on your configuration) that you've configured Oracle to write your archived logs to is full and needs to be cleared out.  Can you free up some space in that directory?

Comment: im very newbie to oracle. im using 11g, i donot know where archived logs are located to freeup space. :( please let me know. thanks

Comment: @Praveenb - OK, so you are the DBA?  From a command-line, open SQL*Plus and connect to the database as SYSDBA.  To do that, type "sqlplus sys/<<password>>@<<tns alias>> as sysdba" at the command line.  Type the command "show parameter archive" and post the results by editing your question.

Comment: i've to run this commands at local system or at server ?.  db is in linux server. im sorry if i ask a silly questions.

Comment: @Praveenb - If the server allows remote connections to the database as SYSDBA, you could do it from either the client or the server.  If not, you'd have to do it from the server.

Comment: I found this link very helpful: http://www.xtivia.com/ora-00257-archiver-error-connect-internal-freed/

Answer (score 2):

Check your the alert log on the Oracle server and also that you have available disk space in the archive log destination.  This error can be triggered by an archiver error when it is unable to archive redo logs.

You can login as the dba and do:  `show parameter archive` as Justin explained in his comment.

You're looking for entries such as `log_archive_dest_N`.  You will likely have numerous of these parameters, and I would suggest checking each drive/location that has a value.

My database for instance has `log_archive_dest_1 = '/o296/dbSID/arch'`

Comment: im very newbie to oracle. im using 11g, i donot know where alert logs are located to freeup space. :( please let me know. thanks